# Passing associative array with spaces on its keys to PHP using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can't pass my keys properly to my PHP server.
Here's an example of my code

```
ajax: {
   url: "<?= base_url("items/getTableData") ?>",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
     table: "users",
     select: "users.*, ut.name as user_type",
     join: {
        ["user_type as ut"]: "ut.id = users.user_type"
     },
     where: "users.status = 1"
   }
},
```

And within my PHP, it will only give me $_POST['join'][0] instead of $_POST['join']['user_type as ut']

Anyone else having this issue? Is this even possible on jQuery?

Expected result: In my PHP, I should receive $_POST['join']['user_type as ut'] instead of $_POST['join'][0].

I tried

```
join: {
   [escape("user_type as ut")]: "ut.id = users.user_type"
},
```

And,

```
join: {
   [encodeURIComponent("user_type as ut")]: "ut.id = users.user_type"
},
```

Comment: Are you sending SQL queries from frontend?

Comment: use the `form.serialize()` concept to send whole form data in one go, rather than defining each key-value pair.

Comment: JSON does not allow spaces in keys.

Comment: @nice_dev i am, is that a bad practice?

Comment: @Dr.Alivetodie-Anant i'm not sure if .serialize helps as this data isn't inside a form

Comment: @Peepo Yes, it is open to all kinds of hacking attacks. Why do you wish to show what queries you will be running on a server on the browser?

Comment: @MarkusZeller i tried giving my json keys some spaces, and it seems to work fine. this limitation somehow only happens when passing through AJAX.

Comment: @nice_dev i see, to be honest, i'm not that aware when i was writing this code lol. i'll keep that in mind and keep my queries inside my php from now on.

Comment: @Peepo Yes please and this would also completely eliminate your current issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been brought up to me that putting your SQL queries in your Javascript code is very vulnerable to hacking attacks (oops!) so I'll have to redo the code eliminating the problem.

Although, if anyone is looking for an answer to this problem:

I just brute-forced it by replacing my space with double underscores (__)

```
join: {
   ["user_type__a__ut"]: "ut.id = users.user_type"
},
```

And putting my $_POST into this function:

```
function fixArrayKeys($arr)
    {
        $newArr = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {

            if(is_array($val)) $val = fixArrayKeys($val);

            if (strpos($key, "__")) $key = str_replace("__", " ", $key);

            if (strpos($key, "_p_")) $key = str_replace("_p_", ".", $key);

            $newArr[$key] = $val;
        }

        return $newArr;
    }
```

This simply replaces the double underscores (__) in the key and give it spaces, "solving" the issue. It doesn't look as good of a solution.

You can edit what alternative keywords you want, mine is double underscores for my space (__) and double underscores with a "p" (_ p _) in the middle to represent a period (.)

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Accepting this answer for now, I will edit this accordingly if there are any other solutions addressing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets represent an array in JSON struct. This syntax looks incorrect to me, it's not a valid JSON object. What are those brackets around `"user_type as ut"` for?

Just remove the brackets, it should work then

```json
join: {
    "user_type as ut": "ut.id = users.user_type"
},
```

By the way, spaces are allowed in JSON keys, but the key should be quoted as you did.

Comment: I did do this when I initially created the code, and that's how this issue started. Surprisingly, square brackets are valid on JSON structs as this is how you put string variables if you want to use them. I tried to do [escape("user_type as ut")] so that's why the brackets were there.